# "no path found" error when pushing to a remote git repository

Tags: github, cd

I have been trying to push my first project to github, but no success whatsoever. I have two errors:

1. When I specify the path of the folder (cd Desktop/folder), I get yhe message:no path found. The name is correct, so how can I overcome this? Also,I am not sure how critical this error is.
2. Following the steps in the github tutorial on the freecodecamp website, after push command I get the error: everything is up to date but,in fact, no changes are done to the repository and nothing is uploaded.

I appreciate clear answers because I am not too technical myself and this is my first project to upload.

Many thanks!

Comment: share your error log here

Answer (score 1):

please find below link which will help you from the very beginning how all process done you will know through conceptually

https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners